# running 2 sites on iis-express (from visual studio 2015) it crushes the first one when the second launch: iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 666

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I have a solution with 2 web sites.
When I try to run the both,
iis express crushes with error:

> The program '[31548] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The program '[31548] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 666 (0x29a).

each one can run on it's own, but when I launch the 2nd one, the 1st one crushes....

Visual Studio 2015, used to run perfectly on VS 2010.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Saw you posted another question. Are they related to each other? Make sure you reveal enough info as such error messages are almost useless. The actual config file matters.

Comment: same project, different issues. but one more info - these where upgraded projects from old version of VS. it doesn't happen on new ones.

Comment: It happened on the new project as well. it looks like the problem is running 2 websites from the same solution.